# extracting key_value in python with more than one column with same name in csv

Tags: python

I have below data in csv :

[image]

I am using below code to extract key-value pair and see the output :

[image]

However I am getting same output as csv file

[image]

Process finished with exit code 0

But I need output like this :

[image]

Please help!

As per your convenience here is the csv data and the code :

CSV Data

===================================

```
A,B,C,D,A,C,D
1,2,1,4,,,
,4,,6,9,8,
13,12,,,,19,84
```

Python Code :

====================================

```
import csv

with open('sample.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Comment: You can not use DictReader in this case, because keys are not unique and when creating the dict per row, last seen wins, e.g. first key `'A'` has value  1, but then it's updated to have value `''`. Same for `C` and `D` keys.You need to parse this yourself.

Comment: It will help if you provide sample input and expected output and extra detail like dies the order of keys matter, etc,

Comment: You edited the output you claim to be getting and now it doesn't match your code snippet.

Comment: sorry Buran, but I am new to stack overflow and hence uploaded wrong output. You can see my requirement now. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are going to post output, please format it accordingly. I edited your question to propely format your output and you revert it back. And it still not match your code

Comment: please post the content of sample.csv

Comment: I have posted the output and the requirement screenshot now. Kindly have a look.

Comment: @NguyenTanBao : Content of csv is there only in the screen shot.

Comment: Instead of images, it would be better if you copy-paste the text for both code as well as data.

Comment: Here is the data :

A B C D A C D
1 2 1 4   
 4  6 9 8 
13 12    19 84

and here is the code 

import csv

with open('sample.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    for row in reader:
        print(row)

Comment: I have edited the post now and put the code and data there.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in comments - you need to parse it on your own

```
import csv
# fieldnames = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
with open('sample.csv', 'r') as csv_file, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as out_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    header = next(reader)
    fieldnames = list({key:None for key in header}) # create from first row
    wrtr = csv.DictWriter(out_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    wrtr.writeheader()
    for row in reader:
        data = {key:value for key, value in zip(header, row) if value}
        wrtr.writerow(data)
```

**output.csv**

```
A,B,C,D
1,2,1,4
9,4,8,6
13,12,19,84
```

Comment: Thanks Buran your code helped me a lot. Moreover I have extended this code and have put the automatic fieldname loading to csv file rather than manually declaring it.

import csv #fieldnames = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E') reader = csv.DictReader(open('sample.csv')) header_all=reader.fieldnames

used = set() fieldnames = [x for x in header_all if x not in used and (used.add(x) or True)]

print(fieldnames)

Comment: If you use `csv.DictReader`, instead of `csv.reader` to read your input file this will set you back where you started in the first place with your question, before you started editing it. I edited my answer to automatically create `fieldnames` from first row in input file.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case. The verbose solution, rather for educational purposes:

```
csv = '''A,B,C,D,A,C,D
1,2,1,4,,,
,4,,6,9,8,
13,12,,,,19,84'''

# parse csv
data    = [cell.split(',') for cell in csv.splitlines()]
letters = data[0]     # first line -- letters
body    = data[1:]    # rest lines

# make a dict {'A':[], 'B': [], 'C': [], 'D':[]}
dic = {}
for letter in letters:
    if letter not in dic: dic[letter] = []

# fill the dict with lists of numbers {'A':[[...],[...]], 'B':[...], ...}
for i, letter in enumerate(letters):
    dic[letter].append([line[i] for line in body])

# function takes nested lists [['a','']['','b']]
# and returns a list with non-empty values from the rest nested lists ['a','b']
def get_list_with_non_empty_values(lists):
    if len(lists) == 1: return lists[0]
    for lst in lists[1:]:
        for i, cell in enumerate(lst):
            if cell: lists[0][i] = cell # if the cell is non empty take it
    return lists[0]

# loop through the dict and apply the function
for letter in dic:
    dic[letter] = get_list_with_non_empty_values(dic[letter])

# turn the dict back into a table
data = [[cell for cell in dic]]
for i in range(len(dic)-1):
    data.append([dic[letter][i] for letter in dic])

print(data)
```

Output:

```
[[  'A',  'B',  'C',  'D' ],
 [  '1',  '2',  '1',  '4' ],
 [  '9',  '4',  '8',  '6' ],
 [ '13', '12', '19', '84' ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

One more code I have made for this situation. Please see the below code. It works as generic solution by passing the argument as file name in the command line like

python script_name.py sample.csv :

```
import csv ,  sys
from datetime import datetime
InputFile=sys.argv[1]
print (InputFile)
now = datetime.now()
OS=str(now )+ ' : Processing file - ' + InputFile
print(OS)
LC=0
OutputFile= InputFile+'.done'
I= open(InputFile)
csv_f = csv.reader(I)
O=open(OutputFile,'w')


def listToString(s):

    # initialize an empty string
    str1 = ""
    e=0

    # traverse in the string
    for ele in s:
        if e==0:
            str1 += ele
            e+=1
        else:
            str1 += ','+ele
            e+=1

    # return string
    return str1+'\n'


for row in csv_f:
    if LC==0:
        HEADER=row
        #print (HEADER)
        uheads = list(dict.fromkeys(HEADER))
        #print(uheads)
        #print(listToString(uheads))
        STR=listToString(uheads)
        O.write(STR)
        LC=LC+1
            #print(uheads)


    else:
        #print (row)
        ROWS=row
        while '' in ROWS:
            ROWS.remove('')
        #print(listToString(ROWS))
        STR=listToString(ROWS)
        O.write(STR )
        LC=LC+1
I.close()
O.close()
```